# Recursive method not returning anything

Tags: java, recursion, netbeans, greedy

I am writing a greedy algorithm that uses a recursive method to count how many coins and each coin denomination it uses to give change accordingly to the change amount.

I'm having problems with the recurssive method because it does not return any data, i thing the problem is within my object use with recursion. I didnt include it but, i already have the properly gets and sets methods.
In the first method i solve the problem using only iteration, but when i run the second method (using recursion), i have no success.

```
public class GreedyAlgorithmPlatzi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Change change = new Change();
        //Method (1)
        System.out.println("USING ITERATIVE METHOD");
        System.out.println(change.greedyChange(35));

        //Method (2)
        System.out.println("USING RECURSIVE METHOD");
        System.out.println(change.greedyRecursivo(35,change.getCoinSet().length));

    }

    static class Change {

        int change, cant20 = 0, cant10 = 0, cant5 = 0, cant1 = 0;
        int coinSet[] = {1, 5, 10, 20};

        //THIS METHOD(1) (ITERATIVELY) returns the amount of coins and //its denominations used to give change, accordingly to the change //parameter
        Change greedyChange(int cambio) {
            Change ch = new Change();
            int num;
            int monedas = 0;
            for (int i = 3; i > -1; i--) {
                num = cambio / this.coinSet[i];
                if (num > 0) {
                    monedas += num;
                    cambio -= (num * this.coinSet[i]);
                    switch (this.coinSet[i]) {
                        case 20:
                            cant20 += monedas;
                            ch.setCant20(cant20);
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            cant10 += monedas - cant20;
                            ch.setCant10(cant10);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            cant5 += monedas - cant20 - cant10;
                            ch.setCant5(cant5);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            cant1 += monedas - cant20 - cant10 - cant5;
                            ch.setCant1(cant1);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            ch.setChange(monedas);
            return ch;
        }

        //THIS METHOD(2) (RECURSIVELY) returns the amount of coins and its denominations used to give change, accordingly to the change parameter
        Change greedyRecursivo(int change,int size) {
            Change chan = new Change();
            chan.setChange(change);
            if (chan.getChange() == 0 || chan.getChange() < 0) {
                chan.setChange(0);
                return chan;
            }

            int numMonedas = 0, numTotal = 0;

            numTotal = (chan.getChange() / this.coinSet[size - 1]);

            if (numTotal > 0) {
                numMonedas += numTotal;
                change -= (numTotal * this.coinSet[size - 1]);
                chan.setChange(change);
                switch (this.coinSet[size - 1]) {
                    case 20:
                        this.cant20 += numMonedas;
                        chan.setCant20(cant20);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        this.cant10 += numMonedas;
                        chan.setCant10(cant10);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        this.cant5 += numMonedas;
                        chan.setCant5(cant5);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        this.cant1 += numMonedas;
                        chan.setCant1(cant1);
                        break;
                }
            }

            chan =  greedyRecursivo(chan.getChange(),size - 1);

            return chan;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Amount of coins used: "
                     + change + ", " + cant20 + " of $20" + ", " + cant10 + " of $10"
                    + ", " + cant5 + " of $5" + ", " + cant1 + " of $1";
        }
```

This is what i get:
USING ITERATIVE METHOD
Amount of coins used: 3, 1 of $20, 1 of $10, 1 of $5, 0 of $1.
USING RECURSIVE METHOD
Amount of coins used: 0, 0 of $20, 0 of $10, 0 of $5, 0 of $1

This is what im supposed to get:
USING ITERATIVE METHOD
Amount of coins used: 3, 1 of $20, 1 of $10, 1 of $5, 0 of $1
USING RECURSIVE METHOD
Amount of coins used: 3, 1 of $20, 1 of $10, 1 of $5, 0 of $1

Comment: Your recursive method creates a new `Change` object for each recursive call. If you want the object to remember it all, you should probably only have one object, regardless of how many times the recursive method calls itself. Re-think your logic.

Comment: Further - note that the innermost ```Change``` will always have value 0, and that instance gets passed all the way out as each return value as the call stack unwinds.

Comment: thanks both, i noticed what you pointed out @Andreas and now im working on it!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i found to the problem: changed the method to a void type insted of an object type and it worked well.

```
void greedyRecursivo(int change,int size) {

        setChange(change);
        if (getChange() == 0 || getChange() < 0) {

            return;
        }

        int numMonedas = 0, numTotal = 0;

        numTotal = (getChange() / this.coinSet[size - 1]);

        if (numTotal > 0) {
            numMonedas += numTotal;
            change -= (numTotal * this.coinSet[size - 1]);
            setChange(change);
            switch (this.coinSet[size - 1]) {
                case 20:
                    this.cant20 += numMonedas;
                    setCant20(cant20);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    this.cant10 += numMonedas;
                    setCant10(cant10);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    this.cant5 += numMonedas;
                    setCant5(cant5);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.cant1 += numMonedas;
                    setCant1(cant1);
                    break;
            }
        }

        greedyRecursivo(getChange(),size - 1);
       int chan =  cant20+cant10+cant5+cant1;
       if(change == 0){
           System.out.println("Cantidad de monedas utilizadas para dar feria: " + chan + ", " +
                cant20 + " de $20, " + + cant10 + " de $10, "+  cant5 + " de $5, "+
                cant1 + " de $1.");
       }

    }
```